# Why cannot I use number as immediate value?

Tags: javascript

Lets use the number `22` as an example.

```
`typeof 22` outputs `number`
`typeof Number(22)` outputs `number`

`Object.prototype.toString.call(22)` outputs `[object Number]`
`Object.prototype.toString.call(Number(22))` outputs `[object Number]`


`22 === Number(22)` outputs `true`

`if(22.toString() === "22") { console.log(true) }` throws `SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`
`if(Number(22).toString() === "22") { console.log(true) }` outputs `true`
```

Why this difference in behaviour? 
I understand that you cannot use numerics as variable names, but I am trying to use it as an immediate value.

Comment: decimal after a number is treated as a decimal point. Give some space to it - try  `22 .toString()`